# Flutter - How to create a CupertinoAlertDialog

Tags: ios, flutter, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to create an iOS `CupertinoAlertDialog` on my Flutter project using the following code:

```
   showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => new CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: new Text("Alert"),
        content: new Text("My alert message"),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(isDefaultAction: true, child: new Text("Close"))
        ]));
```

However, when call this dialog I receive the following error message:

`NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'alertDialogLabel' was called on null`

The Android `AlertDialog` works properly.

What is wrong with this code?

---

Edit:

Solution: [CupertinoAlertDialog crash](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23047#issuecomment-559087527)

Just add `GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate` to your MaterialApp.

Comment: I used your code , i am able to see the dialog.

Comment: That's weird. I'm more confused now...

Comment: Can you tell me which version of the flutter you are using? I'm using 0.9.7-pre.83

Comment: i am using v0.9.6, if you put your full page code , i can run and check .

Comment: I can't put it here because it's huge. The widget itself has only a few lines, but it depends on many other widgets I created. But knowing that the problem isn't with the code itself helps me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thanks, buddy. I had the same problem. `GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate` works.

Answer (score 7):

You create a method and you show the dialog from there

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  void displayDialog() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => new CupertinoAlertDialog(
            title: new Text("Alert"),
            content: new Text("My alert message"),
            actions: [
              CupertinoDialogAction(
                  isDefaultAction: true, child: new Text("Close"))
            ],
          ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Center(child: new Text("Welcome")),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: displayDialog,
        child: new Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this code on a new flutter project and it worked. It is something on my project that is causing this problem.

Comment: It might be a problem with the context. Look that you are not calling showDialog() after you have closed or popped the widget from where you are calling the dialog.

Comment: OK. I will take a look at it. If I find what happened, I'll describe it here.

Comment: please, describe it here :)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. To dismiss, put the `Navigator.of(context).pop("Discard");` in the onPressed()

Answer (score 0):

I had used localization in my project and that was main reason for this **alertDialogLabel** issue.

here is solution worked for me ['alertDialogLabel' was called on null](https://www.programmersought.com/article/79971120845/)